# does Laravel handles mb_internal_encoding and mb_http_output as the article PHP the Right Way said

Tags: utf-8, laravel, laravel-4

Does the Laravel handles the mb_http_output and mb_internal_encoding? Specifically in outputting the response. As per advice in the article: http://www.phptherightway.com/#php_and_utf8

Answer (score 0):

Laravel is using the `Patchwork\Utf8` package and fires the `Bootup::initMbstring` method. (in `bootstrap/autoload.php` )
But I'm not sure which settings are set in there, but this should help you a bit in the right direction.